# Relation between functional measures and states in AQFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, path-integral

Let $(M,g)$ be a globally hyperbolic spacetime and $\phi$ a KG field. In AQFT we consider the algebra of observables $\mathfrak{A}$ generated by $\phi(f)$ where $f\in C^\infty_0(M)$ is a test function.

A state is then a linear functional $\omega : \mathfrak{A}\to\mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $\omega(1)=1$ and $\omega(a^\ast a)\in [0,+\infty)$ for all $a\in \mathfrak{A}$.

Now, a state allows for the computation of the $n$-point functions $$W_n(f_1,\dots,f_n)=\langle \phi(f_1)\cdots \phi(f_n)\rangle_\omega=\omega(\phi(f_1)\cdots \phi(f_n)).\tag{1}$$

Now in usual treatments, one writes via functional integration

$$\langle \operatorname{T}[\phi(x_1)\cdots \phi(x_n)]\rangle=\int \varphi(x_1)\cdots \varphi(x_n)\dfrac{e^{iS[\varphi]}\mathfrak{D}\varphi}{Z}\tag{2}$$

Now if we  make sense of $Z^{-1}e^{-S[\phi]}\mathfrak{D}\phi$ as a functional measure after passing to Euclidean time (which is possible at least for the free theory), there seems to be a one-to-one relation between time-ordered correlators and functional measures. In other words, there seems to be a one-to-one relation between the restriction of $\omega$ to time-ordered products and functional measures.

This makes me wonder, can this be extended to the state $\omega$ itself? Is there some sort of correspondence between states and functional measures so that, for instance, a gaussian state would be in correspondence to a gaussian measure?

Or is this relation between time-ordered products and measures not even one-to-one or even well-defined?

What is the relation between algebraic states and functional measures, if there is any relation?

Comment: Very interesting question. I am however wondering if this can be made sufficiently rigorous even for the vacuum state: passing from Euclidean time to Lorentzian is not completely trivial, since the Osterwalder-Schroder theorem contains some rather non-trivial condition on Euclidean correlators that is needed to ensure Wightman functions are distributions (I have in mind the O-S II paper). I don't know anything about whether this condition can be interpreted naturally in terms of functional measures.

Comment: Identity (2) is wrong because the left-hand side is not symmetric if interchanging $f_k$ and $f_k$ (a causal propagator takes place), whereas the right-hand side is symmetric by construction. Passing to the Euclidean time is a problem in a generic curved globally hyperbolic spacetime... Maybe in **static** spacetimes the question could make some sense, but it is not completely clear how the correlation functions are related with the algebraic state. For Gaussian states it seems to make sense if the states are static.

Comment: @ValterMoretti, I think the question is interesting even in flat space. I also do not understand your comment about identity (2) because there are no $f_k$ in it.

Comment: Yes, you are right sorry, just replace $f_k$ for $x_k$ in my commnent. Indeed, I include Minkowki spacetime in the class of static spacetimes.

Comment: What I wanted to remark is that, in the Lorenzian case, the left-hand side of (2) needs a T product.

Comment: @ValterMoretti thanks for pointing out that quite big mistake. I totally reworded the question. Still, I wonder if there is any relation between states and functional measures. I think an answer in the static case would already be very good. By the way, in globally hyperbolic spacetimes can't we use a foliation by Cauchy surfaces to identify $M\simeq \mathbb{R}\times \Sigma$ and do the usual transformation $\tau = it$ using $t$ the projection onto the first factor? Or the problem then is that the results end up depending on the foliation (so no well-defined measure in the end)?

Comment: @user1620696 The problem with non-static spacetimes is that (1) the metric depends on $t$ and (2) terms $g_{0k}$ appear. The $t$-dependence may be non-analytic so that the Wick rotation cannot performed. If it can be performed, the terms $g_{0k}$ make the final metric complex instead of real. Finally, as you suspect, everything depends on the foliation (but this is not a real problem).

Comment: Regarding the main issue, the functional measure exists only in the Euclidean section (in the Lorentzian one there is no measure which interprets the functional integral). So, a comparison can be made only between the Wick-rotated T-ordered n-point functions (Schwinger functions) and some integral of polynomials with respect to a functional measure over the configuration space. I think that for Gaussian states, this measure is a Gaussian measure, but I suspect that this correspondence cannot rigorously be extended to more general situations.

Comment: On the other hand, the functional integral is very useful for formal manipulations, but its rigorous treatment is almost impossible if excluding elementary cases. In practice one can formally assume that the measure exists just to grasp some insights on the structure of the states and finally he/she can prove everything exploiting the rigorous algebraic approach.